# I want to create in-house store for my 2D game in unity should I create it by using PlayerPrefs or Serializedfield

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 2d

I want to create in-house store for my 2D game in unity should I create it by using PlayerPrefs or Serializedfield or any idea/suggestion you can give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just marking fields with the Serializedfield attribute will allow you to show them in the editor and preserve them in the editor if you modify them.

but they won't be persistant when you reboot the app.

I you want to save values, use PlayerPrefs, or other solutions like writing to file or a database (depending how much data you will save)

Comment: Note that any form of **local** storage (including player prefs) is subject to outside modification. Ie. players could give themselves items they haven't purchased.

Comment: I think that on mobile, the phone would need to be rooted to access the playerpref data. I you really want to ensure nobody tempers with it, you can find some unity assets that provides encrypted playerprefs

Comment: I haven't tried to find payee pref data on a mobile device yet. But you are probably correct. That said, even encrypted, it is inherently less secure that *any* cloud based solution. Unity even says that player pref is not appropriate for things other than application settings (volume level, etc)